# How to create a map for generic types with Mapster?

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, mapster

I need to configure a custom mapping between two generic classes using [Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster).

```
public class Source<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Destination<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I made the following attempts but the syntax is not correct:

```
TypeAdapterConfig<Source<>, Destination<>>.NewConfig()
    .Map(dest => dest.Value, src => src.Value);

TypeAdapterConfig<Source<T>, Destination<T>>.NewConfig()
    .Map(dest => dest.Value, src => src.Value);
```

I searched for an answer and read the Mapster documentation, but couldn't find a solution. Is this a limitation of the mapping library? Is there any way to do this kind of mapping?

Comment: In mapster when you use :TypeAdapterConfig, it means you want to map two entities that is knowing object and the properties are compiled, you can not use that for generic. You should create one by one mapping adapting for your class if you have a hard entities to map. Any way the easiest way to use mapster is this: source.Adapt<EntityName>();

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a generic type with generic type parameters unless you’re in an appropriate generic context. So you cannot just create a mapping for all source/target combinations like this.

You can make things slightly nicer to write via a helper function, like

```cs
public void MapSourceToDestination<T>() {
  TypeAdapterConfig<Source<T>, Destination<T>>.NewConfig()
    .Map(dest => dest.Value, src => src.Value);
}
```

But you would still need to call that for every T to support.

Answer (score 0):

now you can do it like [this](https://github.com/chaowlert/Mapster/wiki/Configuration#open-generics)

```
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.ForType(typeof(GenericPoco<>), typeof(GenericDto<>))
    .Map("value", "Value");
```